# Generating link to Action with Route attribute using asp.core html tags

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to understand those new ASP.CORE tags but can't figur out how to generate link for action with  custome route

Here is my Action:

```
    [Route("[controller]/icatalog/{cartID:int:min(1)}",Name ="CatalogeRoute")]
    [ActionName("Catalog")]
    public IActionResult PublicCatatalog(int cartID)
    {   
    return View("Cart")
    }
```

Genereation in 'old' way working fine

Working:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Catalog","Home",new {basketID=1 })">Test2</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Link("CatalogeRoute",new {card=1 })"> Test3</a>
```

But ASP.CORE tags not working:

```
  <a asp-action="Catalog" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-id="1">Test1</a>
```

Comment: Try `asp-route-cartID` instead.

Comment: yeap now it works. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use attributes that match your action parameter names.
So in this case:

```
<a asp-action="Catalog" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-cartID="1">Test1</a>
```